# NPM warning installation calling for solution when installing Foundation

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal, zurb-foundation

I need a help with this error while i'm installing npm in the directory. it caused an error too when I try to npm start. I have tried with npm cache clean --force and rm -rf node_modules but it doesnt work. Hope anyone can help in here thanks!

```
1 warning and 14 errors generated.

make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1

gyp ERR! build error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/Users/Faradila/Development/blog/foundation/videotalent/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0

gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/Faradila/Development/blog/foundation/videotalent/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Faradila/Development/blog/foundation/videotalent/node_modules/node-sass

gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.1

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok 

Build failed with error code: 1

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 install: `node install`

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Do you have XCode installed? node-gyp is trying to compile some modules written in C++ so you need XCode installed and registered

Comment: Yes I got XCode installed. it works actually in another directory. I think the problem only to the directory where install Foundation. I should have mentioned this.